# object doesn't support this property or method Chartspace

Tags: vbscript

Currently encountered this problem, `object doesn't support this property or method Charspace.constants`

```
<OBJECT id=ChartSpace1 style="WIDTH: 100%; HEIGHT: 80%" classid=clsid:0002E55D-0000-0000-C000-000000000046 width=576 height=384></OBJECT>
```

**Then I call**

```
set c = ChartSpace1.Constants
```

**Then error**

`" object doesn't support this property or method ChartSpace1.Constants "`

Few things I noticed. 
It used to work fine, and after the migration from 32 bit to 64 bit, it seems to give this error
From the clsid, it seems like its using OWC11.dll not OWC older version.
OWC dll only was on 32 bit . Am I right ?

My assumption to fix this is to somehow configure the IIS to accept 32 bit.

I am totally new to this stuff, sorry for any misunderstanding.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Happened to be that office web component was not installed on the client pc in order to use this object in VBScript.

After installing owc11.dll on my client pc, works wonderful.